# UITextField validation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I want to know the textfield and textview validations.what In my app, one textview field and two textfields.

Now what i wanto be done is , when clicking the button without enter any data into textfields then displays the alterview like this please enter details above fields. How to do this?plz explain with simple example.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood your question, but you can implement the [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) protocol in your view controller to observe all changes to your text field. You can do all sorts of things with that, including on the fly validation of the text.

Answer (score 0):

on your button click

```
-(void)yourButtonClicked:(id)sender{
   if([yourTextField.text length] == 0){
       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Enter your details"  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
       [alert show];
       [alert release];
   }
}
```